# Change author in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have commit my code on bitbucket from another computer and forgot to change the name from default to mine. How can i fix wrong name to mine. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [issue 3295](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3295/incorrect-author-name-while-pushing-code) addresses your scenario: "Incorrect Author name while Pushing code to BitBucket repository"

> The author string is something that comes from the configuration on your machine (since you are committing locally and pushing to Bitbucket).
>
> You can set this string for Hg, [**this doc**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+your+username+for+Bitbucket+actions#SetyourusernameforBitbucketactions-Mercurialusername%2Femailconfiguration) talks about doing that.
>   Similarly you can set the Git author, [**this doc**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+your+username+for+Bitbucket+actions#SetyourusernameforBitbucketactions-Gitusername%2Femailconfiguration) talks about that.
>
> As for the commits you have already pushed to Bitbucket Sebastian is right that **you can just map your committer string to your user by clicking on the '`?`'**.
>
> **If you go to the commits screen, you will see a '`?`', click it, and fill out your BB username on the left side, this will link your BB name to your entered commit name**.

Comment: @itslittlejohn I don't mind in the least :) Links updated and restored.